# dom save element to string

Tags: php, xml, string, dom, var

I am trying to put a XML object into an array but i get an emty array and i can't find out why.

```
<?php

$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <confgs>
            # System Settings #
            ############################################################
            ## Login Account Settings

            ADMIN_ID="<confg rang="0" soort="veld" name="config1" />"
            ADMIN_ID="<confg rang="1" soort="veld" name="config2" />"
            ADMIN_PASS="PKXUT1xxRoutIT"
            USER_ID="<confg rang="2" soort="veld" name="config3" />"
            USER_PASS="<confg rang="3" soort="optie" opties="opt1~opt2~opt3" name="config4" />"
            ## Time Adjust Settings
            TIME_ZONE="60"
            DST_ENABLE="Y"
            MAC_ADRES="<confg rang="4" soort="veld" name="config5" />"
            DST_START_MONTH="3"
            DST_START_ORDINAL_DAY="<stconfg rang="1" soort="veld" name="stanconf1" />"
            DST_START_ORDINAL_DAY="<confg rang="8" soort="optie" opties="deze~die~endit~optie~extra" name="kijkhetwerkt" />"
            DST_START_ORDINAL_DAY="5"
            DST_START_ORDINAL_DAY="<stconfg rang="2" soort="veld" name="stanconf2" />"
            DST_START_ORDINAL_DAY="<confg rang="5" soort="veld" name="config6" />"
            DST_START_ORDINAL_DAY="<confg rang="6" soort="optie" opties="dit~dat~bibobla" name="slelect" />"
            IETS_CONF_ORDINAL_CFG="<confg rang="7" soort="veld" name="ditveld" />"
            IETS_CONF_ORDINAL_CFG="<confg rang="9" soort="veld" name="hallo" />"
            </confgs>
          ';

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadXML($string);
    $confg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('confg');

    $form = array();
    $a = 0;

    foreach($confg as $configuratie){
        $a++;
        $form[$a] = $dom->saveXML($configuratie);
    }

print_r($form);
    ?>
```

this is what I get:

Array ( [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => )

something is telling me that my code loops trough all the 10 elements so it has to be there how do i grab it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `<confg ... />` are now HTML elements and cannot be displayed in browser as they are simply HTML tags.

If you view source you will see them.

Comment: Who I feel so stupid now! you are so right they where there all the way I just did not see them, I do now. And i was already thinking why isn't this working but it work all the time.

Comment: :) it happens very often, a second pair of eyes is always best.

Comment: For some reason I can't use the values of the array inside the str_replace function. Why is this?

Comment: Oke I have it working now. Thank you for your answer. I discovered that when XML is saved into string the last space between name="name" /> gets removed so it become's name="name"/>. Therefor i first save my loaded string to the same variable so its comparable XML. Now i can use the array values to remove the element's for [conf_1]. btw, this is just the last step of my code. First I use the XML to create a form. See here what my intentions where [codepad.org/eMm4hYrU](http://codepad.org/eMm4hYrU)